# How can I show COMMAND mode in statusline when entering command-line mode ( " : " ) on VIM?

Tags: vim

I'm starting on VIM (yes, just VIM, not NeoVIM or any other) and I have a StatusLine configured in my .vimrc and which shows the current mode I'm in and all modes are shown correctly except... when I enter Command-line mode (" : ") I want the statusline to show "COMMAND" and it shows "NORMAL" (I added a screenshot at the bottom showing the StatusLine).

I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to install any plugin. I searched a lot for this problem and I didn't find anything related with this specific problem... Thanks!

Here is the `.vimrc` (StatusLine stuff begins where it says " >>>>> Status line") :

**Note:** I know that I have "set noshowmode", but I already did "set showmode" and it didn't work. I only did "set noshowmode" because I don't need the mode to be shown twice...

```
" ------------------   VIM Configuration   -------------------------

set nocompatible " VI compatible mode is disabled so that VIm things work
syntax on " enable syntax processing
syntax enable
set encoding=utf-8

filetype indent on " load filetype-specific indent files
filetype on
filetype plugin on " load filetype specific plugin files


" >>>>> Spaces & Tabs
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set smartindent
" ----------------------------------------------------------


" >>>>> Buffers
set hidden " Allows having hidden buffers without saving them
" ----------------------------------------------------------


" >>>>> UI Config 

set number  " show line numbers 
set colorcolumn=80  "Know where I am
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=white
set nowrap
set scrolloff=8

set wildmenu  " visual autocomplete for command menu 

set nobackup " backup file is immediately deleted upon successfully writing the original file.
set noswapfile

let python_highlight_all=1
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
" ----------------------------------------------------------


" >>>>> Searching

set path+=**
set incsearch         " search as characters are entered
set ignorecase        " Ignore case in searches by default
set smartcase         " But make it case sensitive if an uppercase is entered
" ----------------------------------------------------------


" >>>>> Status line

" status bar colors
au InsertEnter * hi statusline guifg=black guibg=#d7afff ctermfg=black ctermbg=magenta
au InsertLeave * hi statusline guifg=black guibg=#8fbfdc ctermfg=black ctermbg=cyan
hi statusline guifg=black guibg=#8fbfdc ctermfg=black ctermbg=cyan

" default: set statusline=%f\ %h%w%m%r\ %=%(%l,%c%V\ %=\ %P%)

" Status Line Custom
let g:currentmode={
    \ 'n'  : 'Normal',
    \ 'no' : 'Normal·Operator Pending',
    \ 'v'  : 'Visual',
    \ 'V'  : 'V·Line',
    \ '^V' : 'V·Block',
    \ 's'  : 'Select',
    \ 'S'  : 'S·Line',
    \ '^S' : 'S·Block',
    \ 'i'  : 'Insert',
    \ 'R'  : 'Replace',
    \ 'Rv' : 'V·Replace',
    \ 'c'  : 'Command',
    \ 'cv' : 'Vim Ex',
    \ 'ce' : 'Ex',
    \ 'r'  : 'Prompt',
    \ 'rm' : 'More',
    \ 'r?' : 'Confirm',
    \ '!'  : 'Shell',
    \ 't'  : 'Terminal'
    \}

set laststatus=2
set noshowmode
set statusline=
set statusline+=%0*\ %n\                                 " Buffer number
set statusline+=%1*\ %<%F%m%r%h%w\                       " File path, modified, readonly, helpfile, preview
set statusline+=%3*│                                     " Separator
set statusline+=%2*\ %Y\                                 " FileType
set statusline+=%3*│                                     " Separator
set statusline+=%2*\ %{''.(&fenc!=''?&fenc:&enc).''}     " Encoding
set statusline+=\ (%{&ff})                               " FileFormat (dos/unix..)
set statusline+=%=                                       " Right Side
set statusline+=%2*\ col:\ %02v\                         " Column number
set statusline+=%3*│                                     " Separator
set statusline+=%1*\ ln:\ %02l/%L\ (%3p%%)\              " Line number / total lines, percentage of document
set statusline+=%0*\ %{toupper(g:currentmode[mode()])}\  " The current mode

hi User1 ctermfg=007 ctermbg=239 guibg=#4e4e4e guifg=#adadad 
hi User2 ctermfg=007 ctermbg=236 guibg=#303030 guifg=#adadad
hi User3 ctermfg=236 ctermbg=236 guibg=#303030 guifg=#303030
hi User4 ctermfg=239 ctermbg=239 guibg=#4e4e4e guifg=#4e4e4e
" ----------------------------------------------------------



" >>>>> Netrw (File Tree)

let g:netrw_banner=0        " disable annoying banner
let g:netrw_browse_split=4 " open in prior window
let g:netrw_altv=1          " open splits to the right                    
let g:netrw_liststyle=3     " tree view
let g:netrw_list_hide=netrw_gitignore#Hide()
let g:netrw_list_hide.=',\(^\|\s\s\)\zs\.\S\+'
let g:netrw_winsize = 75
" ----------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: It's *command-line mode*, not "command mode".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I can get:

`autocmd CmdlineEnter * redrawstatus`

As always, autocommands belong in augroups. If you don't know what that means, it means that you want to copy and paste all of the following into your vimrc, not just that first line I gave:

```
augroup statusline
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineEnter * redrawstatus
augroup END
```

Notice that this will not affect all statuslines, just the window which you were in before entering the command line. This answer is not fully tested, or even tested for more than 45 seconds, and I'm sure there's some edge case I have overlooked or some ways this answer can be improved. I will edit this if I think of those. Whether `CmdlineLeave` is worth adding, I'm not sure. I am sure that `CmdlineChanged` is a bad idea to add.

Now for the rest of your vimrc. There are some things you probably want to change in it. For instance:

- take out `set nocompatible`
- use `syntax on` or `syntax enable`, but not both. It's redundant
- `filetype plugin indent on` can be one line, not three, but I guess it doesn't matter
- settings `tabstop` to something other than 8 can screw with things, and any behavior that you want can almost certainly be achieved with other settings
- `smartindent` is outdated and no longer recommended by certain members of the community whom I trust
- adding `**` to `path` is commonly done, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea
- no `hlsearch`?
- autocommands should be in augroups
- in `g:currentmode`, are `^V` and `^S` each one character or two? They won't match if they're two

And that's as far as I looked. I'm sure there's more others can recommend. If you don't want to directly `runtime` it, `defaults.vim` isn't a bad place to look for vimrc ideas.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solve my problem, and also thanks for the suggestions!  I'm new to VIM so I don't know much about it. If you have the time could you please expand on `set nocompatible`, `tabstop` and the `** path` ? Most of the stuff I found out on youtube/google. And, don't know if you can help me here: do you suggest me to move to NeoVIM(or other) and do I need plugins to write code in PHP 7+?

Comment: `set nocompatible` is mostly just useless. When vim starts, it starts with `compatible` set. However, when it finds your user `.vimrc` file, it automatically sets `nocompatible`. So there's no point having `set nocompatible` in a file whose existence already sets `nocompatible`. If you take that line out and restart vim, then do `:set compatible?` it will say `nocompatible`, because it sets it even without you telling it to. `set nocompatible` actually has some side effects too, which you might not want.

Comment: As for `tabstop`, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/wiki/tabstop) is a good read, especially where it says to read the help. It's a lot of text, so just know that it's not too important for you right now and you can leave it be if you want. Same with `path`. It's not bad to have it that way if you want to leave it so for now, it's just less helpful than it could be. [This](https://vimways.org/2018/death-by-a-thousand-files/) is a good, but also rather advanced read on path. Also, `**` might actually be what you want to set it to in the end.

Comment: As for neovim, I have no opinion. I don't use it and I don't see a good reason to. I also have one or two unrelated reasons no to use the project, but they don't affect you. If you want to look into it feel free, but for now I would say just learn vim and if you discover neovim is a better option for you later almost all your knowledge will transfer.

Comment: Writing PHP with vim is easy. I assume you know how to type characters into vim and save the file, so you can clearly write PHP, no plugins needed. Of course that answer is a little unhelpful but I wrote it to make a point. What tools do you consider necessary for you to be an effective PHP developer? Once you figure that out, you can see whether vim provides those tools itself, whether they are available through plugins, or whether a different editor or IDE is more suited to your needs than vim.

Comment: I found I wanted to only `:redrawstatus` if `state('s') == ''`, otherwise it causes existing messages to be hidden, which is annoying. For example the password prompt for `:X` was invisible, or trying to do `:b` to select a buffer after `:ls` would cause the list of buffers to be hidden.